# Coroutine not resuming after WaitForSeconds once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private IEnumerator testCoroutine()
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log("2");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log("3");
}
```

When I StartCoroutine(testCoroutine()) in **Start** method, the coroutine working fine.
But when I call it from another function, the coroutine only print "1", not 2 and 3

```
public void Battle()
{
    StartCoroutine(testCoroutine());
}

public void EnableBattleScene()
{
    UIBattleScene.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Battle();
}
```

EnableBattleScene is called when the player is in contact with the enemy.

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: `yield return` works by being called multiple times (it's an enumerator, that's what they do).  Where are you calling `testCoroutine` multiple times?

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based elapsed function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Comment: @Neil I thought start only called once? That's why I tried to call coroutine once too from another function

Comment: @MickyD Oh, I never knew that coroutine is considered a bad habit, thanks for the info!

Comment: If the caller is disabled, coroutine will stop too.

Comment: @shingo The GameObject attached by this script is never disabled because I want the GameObject to always be active so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: There are some misleading comments here. Neil's comment is incorrect; you can have multiple yields in a coroutine. MickyD's comment is odd; coroutines are standard practice, they are low impact and well understood. Please don't be afraid to use them, they are an essential tool!

Comment: @Absinthe nonsense.  Coroutines are as dangerous as Application.DoEvents; they misuse the purpose of yield; and over complicate matters when a simple timespan measurement would suffice.   No other game engine uses them.   They make for an unpredictable engine flow and likely to lead to corrupted or re-entrant state.  Avoid.

Comment: @MickyD You can pretty much guarantee that every Unity game ever shipped uses a ton of coroutines. If they were some horrendous risk the news would have spread by now. You keep saying "as dangerous as Application.DoEvents" but don't provide any evidence or reasoning. Please don't dissuade new developers from using standard tools without any reason, that does more harm than good.

Comment: @Absinthe please don’t promote bad habits.  Fast Food is also popular, doesn’t mean it’s good for you.  I’ll stick with Fine Dining.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the problem is because I set the timescale to 0.

Instead of using WaitForSeconds, I must use WaitForSecondsRealtime so it's not affected by frame

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).